# IndexedDB in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, indexeddb

I've been trying to test a web app for which I used indexedDB in PhantomJS. Theoretically, as far as I understood, there is support for IndexedDB in PhantomJS > 2 (I have the 2.1.1 version, for 64 bit Linux). However, I couldn't get it to work. 
If I put this code into the web console, it works:

```
var db;
var req = window.indexedDB.open('_pouch_test');
req.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log("error: ");
};

req.onsuccess = function (event) {
    db = req.result;
    console.log("success: " + db);
    var transaction = db.transaction(["by-sequence"]);
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("by-sequence");
    var index = objectStore.index("_doc_id");
    index.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            console.log(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }
    };
    transaction.oncomplete = function () {
        db.close();
    };
};
```

So I tried to run kind of the same thing with Phantom:

**main.js**

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    server = 'http://localhost:8000/testinx';


var test;
page.open(server, function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to get!');
    } else {
        console.log("STARTING");
        if (page.injectJs('raw_get_obj.js')) {
            var title = page.evaluate(function() {
                return getObj();
            });
            if(obj.length < 0)
                console.log("No result");
            console.log(title);
            phantom.exit();
        }
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

**raw_get_obj.js**

```
function getObj()
{
    var arr = [];
    var db;
    var req = window.indexedDB.open('_pouch_test');
    req.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log("error: ");
    };

    req.onsuccess = function (event) {
        db = req.result;
        console.log("success: " + db);
        var transaction = db.transaction(["by-sequence"]);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("by-sequence");
        var index = objectStore.index("_doc_id");
        index.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                console.log(cursor.value);
                arr.push(cursor.value);
                cursor.continue();
            }
        };
        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            db.close();
        };
    };
    return arr;
}
```

This returns

> WebSQL threw an error [object SQLError]

I tried to do the include .js thing because the initial code didn't work properly either, that is this one:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    server = 'http://localhost:8000/textinx';

page.open(server, function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to get!');
    } else {
        page.onInitialized = function () {
            page.evaluate(function () {
                var db;
                var req = window.indexedDB.open('_pouch_test');
                req.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.log("error: ");
                };
                req.onsuccess = function (event) {
                    db = req.result;
                    console.log("success: " + db);
                    var transaction = db.transaction(["by-sequence"]);
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("by-sequence");
                    var index = objectStore.index("_doc_id");
                    index.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
                        var cursor = event.target.result;
                        if (cursor) {
                            console.log(cursor.value);
                            cursor.continue();
                        }
                    };
                    transaction.oncomplete = function () {
                        db.close();
                    };
                };
            });
        };
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the thing that I want to do impossible? Mind you, I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed when it comes to tools like PhantomJS.

Comment: Try a newer up-to-date 2.5 beta version of PhantomJS: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads